# iphone application id for facebook connect

Tags: iphone, facebook

In the advanced section of my facebook app that I use for posting feeds to a user's profile from an iphone app, theres a section to enter the "iPhone Application ID".  And it says - "If you have an iPhone app using Connect, fill this in with your Apple-provided application ID."

I entered my app id.  But when I post anything via the iphone fb connect, I don't see any sort of link to my app.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook developers connection [gives an explanation](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=174597).  Basically when an app is placed on the app store, there is a unique number assigned to the app by Apple to identify it.  This number is the ID they are requesting.

Comment: I enter that number.   I just can't seem to figure out what that does exactly since I don't see any link back to my app in the feed, or anything like that.

Comment: That is kind of weird....  I thought you were asking about the number itself.  If I were in your shoes, I would probably just email the app creator and ask why they need the number... ;)

Comment: i am the app creator,  just being missunderstood :)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, just to check that you are using the correct ID, if I this is the link from iTunes:

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/whats-on-reading/id347859140?mt=8

then the bit that you use for the iPhone Application ID field in Facebook is:

346859140

Is that what you did?  Did you solve this?  I only did this a few hours ago so am hoping it is just the time it takes to replicate the changes on Facebook.  Would be very interested to know how you got on and if your issue is solved.

Comment: I am using the right ID, but its still not working the way I'd expect based on documentation.  I haven't solved it yet.